# coerce matrix into unitary groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, unitary-matrices, magma-cas

I try to coerce this matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

into $GU(2,9)$.
I used the following command:

```
K:=FiniteField(9);

G:=GeneralUnitaryGroup(2,K);

G![[K.1^4,0],[0,1]];
```

Why I keep getting error message telling me:

```
Runtime error in '!': Element is not in the group

LHS: GrpMat

RHS: [[]]
```

At last, I checked the first generator of GU(4,9) from Magma:

```
[  K.1     0     0     0]
[    0     1     0     0]
[    0     0     1     0]
[    0     0     0 K.1^5]
```

So this matrix doesn't satisfy "transpose multiplied by conjugate equals I".. So how the GU is defined here?

Comment: If you call $\mathtt{UnitaryForm(GU(4,9))}$, you will find out!

Comment: Note also that (perhaps confusingly) $\mathtt{GU(4,9)}$ is defined over the field of order $81$, so $\mathtt{GU(4,9)}$ is the same as $\mathtt{GU(4,FiniteField(81))}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
K:=FiniteField(9);
G:=GeneralUnitaryGroup(2,K);
tmat :=TransformForm(IdentityMatrix(GF(9),2), "unitary");
GG := G^(tmat^-1);
GG![[K.1^4,0],[0,1]];
```